# Поиск и вывод на экран из csv файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Есть csv файл со списком студентов и их оценкой. Нужно ввести ,допустим, имя студента и номер его строки в файле и оценку. Как это можно реализовать?

```
name,mark
A,100
Igor,74
Anton,75
Victor,88
B,4
V,5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

парсинг CSV:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
# start indexing from 1
df.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
```

поиск и вывод на экран:

```
In [8]: print(df.query("name == 'Anton'"))
Out[8]:
    name  mark
3  Anton    75
```

PS значения индекса соответствуют номеру строки в CSV файле

PPS данное решение не будет правильно работать если в ячейках CSV файла присутствуют символы перевода строки `"\n"`.

---

**UPDATE:** поиск при помощи переменных:

```
In [10]: find = 'Anton'

In [11]: print(df.query("name == @find"))
    name  mark
3  Anton    75
```

---

```
In [12]: names = ["Anton", "B"]

In [13]: print(df.query("name in @names"))
    name  mark
3  Anton    75
5      B     4
```

Comment: NameError: name 'np' is not defined, что такое np  в данном коде?

Comment: `    filename = input('В каком файле искать?:')
    find = input('Кого найти?:')
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    df.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
    print(df.query("name == find"))`почему я не могу ввести имя ,а потом по моему вводу программа найдет есть ли такая запись,а выдает кучу ошибок?

Comment: @МаксимПронь, дополнил ответ